# How can i sort the dictionary by tuple value?

Tags: python, networkx

kn = nx.karate_club_graph()
kn.nodes(data=True)
[(0, {'club': 'Officer'}), (1, {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}), (2, {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}), (3, {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}), (4, {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}), (5, {'club': 'Officer'}), (6, {'club': 'Officer'}), (7, {'club': 'Mr. Hi'})]

And i want the output to be dictionary which will be sorted first by 'Mr. Hi' club and then by the second one. P.S. i am using Python 3.0

Comment: Dictionaries are not sorted (technically it's an implementation detail)

Comment: Apart from that, I don't even understand the question.

Comment: You will need the OrderedDict type and any handy tutorial on sorting.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are just trying to sort that list of tuples. So in that case, you just need to use `sorted` with a lambda for the `key`. An example of this:

```
mydata =  [(0, {'club': 'Officer'}), (1, {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}), (2, {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}), (3, {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}), (4, {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}), (5, {'club': 'Officer'}), (6, {'club': 'Officer'}), (7, {'club': 'Mr. Hi'})]

mydata_sorted = sorted(mydata, key=lambda x: x[1]['club'])
print(mydata_sorted)
```

will display

```
[(1, {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}), (2, {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}), (3, {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}), (4, {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}), (7, {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}), (0, {'club': 'Officer'}), (5, {'club': 'Officer'}), (6, {'club': 'Officer'})]
```